# Move Layered Navigation below Widget/Banner display

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am on EE but I believe the issue is the same for CE. What I want to do seems very simple. I want all banners in the left hand navigation on a category page to appear above the filter navigation. What I have tried is to change the XML file (search.xml in the case of EE, catalog.xml in the case of CE) by adding the after="-" call.

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="left">
        <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>   
        <block type="enterprise_search/catalog_layer_view" name="enterprisecatalog.leftnav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml" after="-" />  
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

However this does not change anything and Banners still load below Layered Navigation.

If I set the Widget to load in the left column on "All Pages", it will load properly at the top of the column. This solution is undesirable because it also loads the widget on the home page. We only want this to affect Category Pages.

I can also remove the XML block all together and load it as a banner in the widget which allows me to position it anywhere in the left column. This is also undesirable as it breaks our AJAX loading of the page when a layered navigation option is selected.

Does the widget/banner block have a name so I can say after="widget.banner.block.name" in the XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to do this was to use JQuery to push the Widget containing the banners  above the Layered Navigation after load.

```
//Move Category Widget zone above the layered navigation
jQuery(".catalog-category-view .col2-left-layout .col-left .widget").insertBefore(jQuery(".catalog-category-view .col2-left-layout .col-left .block-layered-nav"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You should give your blocks names, and then order them as you wish like so:

```
<block type="whatever" name="something" as="something" 
    template="bla.phtml" before="-" />

<block type="whatever" name="something_else" as="something_else" 
    template="bla.phtml" after="something" />

<block type="whatever" name="something_new" as="something_new" 
    template="bla.phtml" after="something_else" />
```

If you wanted to show the widget on all pages APART from the home page you can set it to show on all pages, and then remove from the homepage only like this:

1) goto CMS -> Pages, then edit homepage

2) add layout update to the page, and specifically remove the widget block:

```
<reference name="left">
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>child_block_name</alias></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: I am specifically asking if the "Widget/Banners" component of EE has a name because you can not declare one in the XML. In fact, widget/banners are NEVER declared in XML in any way ergo my issue with positioning it. "before='-'" is supposed to position it before or after other components but it does not seem to be following the same rules as XML declared content blocks.

Comment: Apologies, I misread. As you said all banners I thought you could have meant the default banner mechanism most people use in Magento with simple banner blocks, which are set in XML :)

Comment: No worries. It is just incredibly frustrating as everything else seems to be well named and structured except for this component. Personally I feel it would be a stronger system if they would let me create and position Widget Blocks like I can any other block in the XML.